# Count the number of cells with a given Manhattan distance from another cell in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, breadth-first-search

We have a matrix `A`, of `M` lines and `N` columns, and a cell `(X, Y)`. We need to find the number of cells in `A` at the Manhattan distance from `(X, Y)` less than or equal to `K`.

Example: In the following matrix, `M = 6`, `N = 7`, `X = 4`, `Y = 3`, `K = 4`. The answer is `32`.
[image]

I can do a BFS from `(X, Y)` and stop after I found all the cells with the given distance. But the matrix can be very huge, so I need a better solution. Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: If k is small it makes no difference what the size of the matrix, right? If k is big I would try to  virtually "draw" a circle with a radius of k. The cells that intersect with the virtual circle are the frontier : put them in the BFS stack. All the cells that are within the frontier should be marked as visited and are part of the solution. In other words : all the cells that their Euclidean distance from the origin is less than k, are part of the solution. All cells that their Euclidean distance from the origin is equal to k are the frontier of the BFS.

Comment: It may be easier and faster to define a square that is bounded by the circle, as the frontier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem ~3 days after posting the question, but I didn't have the time to answer it here. Since I've recently wrote an article on my blog about the solution for this problem, I will link it here: [solution](https://infogenius.ro/problema-rufe-oji-2019-clasa-11/)